# Change default change detection strategy

Tags: angular, angular-changedetection

How to set the default change detection strategy to `OnPush`? Can it be set globally somehow?

I want to avoid having to adding this line to every component

```
@Component({
    ...
    changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    ...
})
```

Comment: What about third-party components that depend on  ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default strategy?

Comment: I suppose they should specify CheckAlways if they depend on it...if in fact the default can be changed easily.

Comment: They wouldn't, because it is framework's default value. I guess you can import your own `Component` that wraps around `ComponenrMetadata` if you really need this behaviour.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The change detection strategy can only be defined per component or directive not globally.

Using a custom decorator is discouraged because it will not be supported by the upcoming offline template compiler.

Comment: Look at next ans, it's possible from cli 
// angular.json
{
  //...
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular": {
      "component": {
        "changeDetection": "OnPush"
      }
    }
  }
}

Comment: @MaxArt thanks :D but downvoting is OK when the answer isn't accurate anymore. Feel free to update though to improve it.

Answer (score 32):

It is possible to set the change detection strategy to OnPush in the CLI so that newly generated components will have it set like that.

```
ng generate component test --changeDetection=OnPush
```

You can also set that value as default in your angular.json, so that you don't need to set the flag every time:

```
// angular.json
{
  //...
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular": {
      "component": {
        "changeDetection": "OnPush"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -3):

You don't want it to be set globally.
`OnPush` will never allow change detection to pass unless

- initial render
- The component is marked as `lViewFlags.dirty`

Having `OnPush` on all components is dangerous unless you really know how Change Detection works.

In short:

- when something happens in a component (user clicks or any other output is triggered), the view and all its parents is marked as `lViewFlags.dirty`
- When an input is set by a parent it is marked as `lViewFlags.dirty`
- running `markForCheck()` wil mark the view and its parents as `lViewFlags.dirty`

So basically every time something happens the view and its parents is dirty anyway, so there is no performance gain of adding `OnPush` on top-level components.

I explained it in detail in this article:
https://blog.simplified.courses/angular-change-detection-onpush-or-not/

Comment: FYI this gets downvoted because it doesn't answer the original question.