# How to set ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush as default strategy

Tags: angular

How to set the ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush as default strategy for every
component in my app instead of writing on every component's template
`changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 Change the default change detection strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37821998/angular2-change-the-default-change-detection-strategy)

Answer (score 59):

It's not possible to set the global ChangeDetection.

However, it is possible to set it on the CLI, so that all components newly generated using `ng generate component` (or `ng g c`) will have it set to `OnPush`.

Run this command to set it:

```
ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.changeDetection OnPush
```

Alternatively (this is what this command does), add this block at the base level of your `angular.json`:

```
// angular.json
{
  //...
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular": {
      "component": {
        "changeDetection": "OnPush"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: But I create components by hand. And what if I later realize that this was not a good idea, we'll need to change all of these components again so that really defeats the purpose of setting a default change detection strategy.